# ILoggingBuilder AddEventLog Linux compatibility

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, logging, event-log

Does the extension method `AddEventLog` of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder` does also work when the application runs under a Linux OS or would it cause an exception when there is no Windows Event Log present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. The event log is windows specific and in fact, if you do try to use it without checking for windows support explicitly, you will get a warning in the IDE:

[image: Image of visual studio showing the AddEventLog call with an analyzer warning because of the code is windows specific]

Comment: In VSCode I do not get any warning. Not even via dotnet build.